# python trying to iterate on key dict in loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to act on a list of dict such as the following - I am trying to print the elements where selected is ==1.

```
a = dict(selected= 1, value = 10)
b = dict(selected= 0, value= 50)
c = dict(selected = 1, value = 150)
list_=[a,b,c]

for element in list_ if element['selected']:
    print(element)
```

But I think I am missing something on the syntax regarding loop, as it produces an error message... Anyone can help me out?

---

EDIT: the error message received: `File "<ipython-input-138-432bd722fae9>", line 6
    for element in list_ if element['selected']:
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Did you perhaps try to extract a loop-and-filter combination from a list comprehension? You can't put a `for` loop and an `if` test on the same line, no. Insert a `:` character and a newline, and adjust the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to separate your for and you if

```
for element in list_:
    if element['selected']:
        print(element)
```

Output

```
{'selected': 1, 'value': 10}
{'selected': 1, 'value': 150}
```

Comment: I have this expression in a jinja template, so I am not sure I can put them on multiple lines

Answer (score -1):

you can simplely write this instead:

```
a = dict(selected= 1, value = 10)
b = dict(selected= 0, value= 50)
c = dict(selected = 1, value = 150)
list_=[a,b,c]
for element in [i for i in list_ if i['selected']]:
    print(element)
```

Comment: This creates a new list solely for the purpose of iterating over, which is unnecessary.